# Why won't the UZBL tabbed browser status bar hide?

Tags: browser, statusbar

I am running the UZBL browser on a Raspberry Pi which is automatically started using Rat Poison.  However, the status bar along the bottom is always displayed even though the "set show_status = 0" is set in the config file.

I can provide a copy of the config file upon request.

Cheers,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

I think it may have been a bug:

https://github.com/uzbl/uzbl/commit/52953866856fab2d180508b11f58536e05dfdf19